# API Platform dont filter on range properties

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Hello I need help under APIPlatform on Symfony Entity I can't get all the filters to work here is a screenshot of my swagger as an attachment and here are the annotations my Offers entity (which I am going to rename to Offer by the way) I know that we have choice in APIPlatform to configure the filters in the apiplatform.yaml service or by annotations. Can it be caused by my relation between Offers and Cars Table (price kilometers and years are from Car related table) here is my code:

My Symfony  Offers Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\OffersRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\RangeFilter;



#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: OffersRepository::class)]
//#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['reference'])]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['reference'],message: 'Ce titre ou reference existe déjà !')]
#[ApiResource] //(paginationMaximumItemsPerPage: 4)
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['offer_title' => 'partial', 'reference' => 'exact'])]
#[ApiFilter(RangeFilter::class, properties: ['cars.price','cars.kilometers','cars.year'])]



class Offers
{
//My Entity Annotations and proprieties
}
```

My api_platform.yaml configuration

```
api_platform:
    title: Hello API Platform
    version: 1.0.0
    enable_profiler: true
    formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
    docs_formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
        jsonopenapi: ['application/vnd.openapi+json']
        html: ['text/html']
    defaults:
        stateless: true
        cache_headers:
            vary: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin']
        extra_properties:
            standard_put: true
            rfc_7807_compliant_errors: true
    event_listeners_backward_compatibility_layer: false
    keep_legacy_inflector: false
```

My APIPlatform schema :

My schema here (i forgot to add schema at first when posting^^) : [myschema](https://sharemycode.io/c/00ab0db)

[image: my swagger view]

Many manipulations who part-fixed my issue like change #[ApiRessource] annotation and trying to clear cache and restarting server
StackOveerflow topics
APIPlaform Official Documentation on filtering